# Powered USB3 hub

Tags: laptop, usb, power-supply, hub

Sounds easy, right?

**NOPE!**

In an attempt to do away with this dreaded message:

[image: USB low power notice from Mac OS]

I am looking for a USB hub for my Macbook Pro that meets the following requirements:

- Externally powered on *all* ports (the hub has its own power jack)
- USB3 support at full speed
- More than 4 ports
- Good reviews (>= 4 stars)

I am specifically *not* looking for, and am not interested in:

- "Charging" hubs meaning:

  - Hubs that only supply power on a subset of the available ports,
  - Or hubs that only supply power without connection to the PC
- "House brand" hubs such as AmazonBasics, Gigatech, etc. Too many bad experiences there.

Price is no object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a good USB Hub with more than 4 ports is what you are looking for then you should check out Anker USB Hubs like this one

https://www.anker.com/products/A7513141

It's a 7 port Aluminum hub, USB 3.0, with a 5V 3.0A power adapter.

As for reviews....

**Their site:**

[image]

**From Amazon:**

[image]

They make hubs that go from 4 ports to 14 ports so there is a lot of choice.  **What what I really like about their products is that they stand behind them.**  I had an issue with a 2 port hub over a year after I bought it and they refunded my full purchase price.   Their customer service has been fantastic that I can recommend them and their products without hesitation.

Comment: I have a few Anker products, though not this particular one. I've never had an issue with any of them.